# How do I tighten the header space in Blogger

Tags: css, header, blogger

I want to reduce the space between menu and top of header. I just want enough space for the blog title. `www.travelinsightsblog.blogspot.com`

I have tried the following but  didn't reduce the space

```
tabs-outer {
margin-top: -15px !important;}

.header-outer {
margin-top: -25px !important;}
```

Suggestions appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to set the margin of the near elements

```
.header-inner .Header .descriptionwrapper {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#HTML1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Also, If you want to reduce the title font size:

```
.Header .title {
    font-size: 45px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it doses the job.

Comment: On mobile, the screen is shaky. There is a line at the bottom and on right side while scrolling down the screen. My other website is stable, there is no movement of the screen display. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: I've checked your site, but there aren't any issues.

Comment: I have checked the blog on iphone and note. On laptop I have no issues. On mobile, as I scroll down the entire screen can move left, right, top and bottom. When I click on a menu item the screen jerks. The blog is renamed as https://www.travelscrolls.com.  I dont't have this issue on my other site www.tutorhubllc.com on mobile

Comment: OK, it's because the Contact Form input size. add this to CSS `.mobile footer { padding: 15px }
.mobile .contact-form-name, .mobile .contact-form-email, .mobile .contact-form-email-message { width: 100% }`

Comment: It is fixed after removing Adsense. Now I have to figure out how to use Adsense so it doesn't mess things up.